# Using ParticleSystem for TouchEvent

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to use andengines particle system to have a streak of a certain color when the user drags their finger across the screen or touches the screen. I want it to recognize touchevents which is quite simple in angegine. I cant seem to figure out how i need to do the particle system for my use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!